# Can't run gitlab using exising Nginx installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, nginx, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I have installed Gitlab through omnibus installation with existing NGINX installation. I was following the docs guide, installed Passenger using this guide (it also updated my installed nginx): https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/xenial/

Also i've updated /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb to following settings:

```
external_url 'http://git.domain.kz'
nginx['enable'] = false
```

Here's the output of command `sudo gitlab-ctl tail`

https://pastebin.com/XKAwUY3U

Comment: I would suggest you let it run on port 8080 and then from existing Nginx use `proxy_pass`.

Comment: Could you throw an example on how to do that?

Comment: See this https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#setting-the-nginx-listen-port. In your own nginx create a simple config `server { listen 80; server_name git.domian.kz; location / { proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;} }`

Comment: Just `proxy_pass` and that's all?

Comment: Yes that should do it. You might need to add `proxy_set_header Host $host;` also if that doesn't work